# Is this a topological space?

Tags: general-topology

$X = R$ and a subset $U \subset \mathbb{R}$ is open if and only if $U$ is infinite or $U = \emptyset$.

Am I correct in saying that it isn't a topological space because $(-\infty,0)$ and $(0,\infty)$ would be open in R but not their union? Or is there a better answer?

Comment: Do you mean "intersection"?

Comment: That too - $(-\infty,0)\cap(0,+\infty)=\emptyset$ *is* explicitly open.

Answer (score 3):

The union of $(-\infty, 0)\cup(0,+\infty)$ (is infinite) and intersection  $(-\infty, 0)\cap(0,+\infty)=\emptyset$ still open by your definition.

**Hint**:

Both $(-\infty, 0]$ and $[0,+\infty)$ are infinite, then open.

But $(-\infty, 0] \cap [0,+\infty)=\{0\}$. What can you conclude?

Comment: In fact the same argument can be used to show the topology generated by infinite sets is the discrete topology.

Answer (score 0):

Your "reason" is wrong: the union is infinite so in the collection too.

But there *are* finite *intersections* of infinite sets that are not infinite nor empty, e.g. $[0,+\infty) \cap [-\infty,0] = \{0\}$ is one such example and suffices to disprove that the collection you described is a topology on $\Bbb R$.